# How to make rule not required when another field is present?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an image upload field which must not be empty when another field is selected to one:

```
required_if:digital_form,1
```

But in some cases the image is already in the database, and I display it in form:

```
@if
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="{{ URL::asset($modelCycleEdit->cover) }}" alt="img" style = "max-width:200px">
{!! Form::hidden('is_cover',1) !!}
@endif
```

In the case the image exists I would like to void the first rule but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
'image' => 'required_with:digital_form,1'
```

**required_with**:: The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.